# JQuery unable to get closest sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this html that will be repeated a few times. I want the .Categories class to update the nearest sibling .Fields class when an ajax request has been completed. I have tried to use.find as well but none seem to work.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label>Document Categories</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, (SelectList)Model.Categories, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control Categories" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label>Document Fields</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldId, (SelectList)Model.DocumentFields, "Select Field", new { @class = "form-control Fields" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label for="Data">Data</label>
        <input type="text" id="Data" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
</div>

$("#datatable-search-input-container").on("change", ".Categories", function (e) {
    console.log("changed");
    selected = $(".Categories").find(":selected").val();
    var form_data = selected;
    refreshDropdown(form_data);
    return false;
});

function refreshDropdown(Input) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetFields", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(Input),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                var parent = $(this).closest(".search-spacing");
                parent.find(".Fields").empty();
                console.log(parent);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: where is class Categories in html?

Comment: It only has a label as it's sibling - siblings are on the same level in the same parent.  To update the field class you would need to go `$(this).parent().next().find('.Fields')`

Comment: @Pete how can I get the next Immediate .Fields class then?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra .Categories is in the DropdownFor

Comment: @JianYA refresh page, was editing my comment although having seen where you are trying to use it, probably won't work as $(this) won't be the category field

Comment: Try `refreshDropdown.call(this, form_data)` then `this` inside your `refreshDropdown` refers to the `element` the `event` was triggered for.
Also cache it 'cause `this` changes in your `ajax listeners`.

Comment: @CodeSpirit so how do i use this in refreshDropdown? this.find(".Fields").empty()?

Comment: @Pete I did this $(this).parent().next().find('.Fields').empty() but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your function to pass in the category input:

```js
$("#datatable-search-input-container").on("change", ".Categories", function (e) {
    console.log("changed");
    var $thisCategory = $(this);
    refreshDropdown($thisCategory);
    return false;
});

function refreshDropdown(Input) {
    var form_data = Input.find(":selected").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetFields", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                var parent = Input.parent();
                parent.next().find(".Fields").empty();
                console.log(parent);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `refreshDropdown.call(this, form_data)` then `this` inside your `refreshDropdown` refers to the `element` the `event` was triggered for.
Also cache it 'cause `this` changes in your `ajax listeners`.

```
$("#datatable-search-input-container").on("change", ".Categories", function (e) {
        console.log("changed");
        selected = $(".Categories").find(":selected").val();
        var form_data = selected;
        refreshDropdown.call(this, form_data);
        return false;
    });

    function refreshDropdown(Input) {
        var $element = $(this),
            $nextFields = $element.parent().nextSibling().children(".Fields");

        $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetFields", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(Input),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $nextFields.empty();
                    console.log(parent);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: It says $element ,parent(...) is not a function though